# Thresholding image in OpenCV of min value

Tags: c++, opencv, threshold

I want to use `cv::threshold` function because it is well optimized rather than looping through the whole image myself.. however it doesn't have a thresholding to a minimum value. That the options available:

[image]

What I want is to set pixels that are smaller than a certain value to that value, example:

```
image.at<float>(j,i) > 0.1f ? image.at<float>(j,i): 0.1f;
```

Can I do that without using loops?

I tried that:

```
image.setTo(0.1, image < 0.1);
```

But it is saying that:

```
 error: no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘const cv::UMat’ and ‘double’)
```

PS: my images are of type cv::UMat

Comment: So make it 2 steps, first use `threshold` to make the mask, and then use it with `setTo`.

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks! I found that cv::max could do the job. Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for a number `x` between 0 and 255 the equivalence `max(x, thresh) == 255 - min(255-x, 255-thresh)` holds and the results stay within [0, 255].

So you can (i) invert the image, (ii) build the max-threshold by `255-thresh`, and (iii) invert again.

Note that mathematically for any constant `a` it holds that
`max(x, thresh) == a - min(a-x, a-thresh)`, e.g., `max(x, thresh) == -min(-x, -thresh)`. The last one is the preferred one for floating-point data.

Comment: That's a solution is valid if you're between 0 and 255 as you said but my image is float! But thanks

Comment: No, it is also a solution for float. You can just replace 255 by any other constant, like 0.0. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found this function:

```
void cv::max(
const Mat& src1, // Input array
double value, // Scalar input
Mat& dst // Result array
);
```

It compares every element of `src1` with `value` and take the maximum, it kind of threshold but with `cv::max` function.